# Add site permission to user in Django/Mezzanine

Tags: django, django-admin

I have no clue how to add permission with this model in Mezzanine:

```
class SitePermission(models.Model):
    """
    Permission relationship between a user and a site that's
    used instead of ``User.is_staff``, for admin and inline-editing
    access.
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(user_model_name, verbose_name=_("Author"),
    related_name="%(class)ss")
    sites = models.ManyToManyField("sites.Site", blank=True,
                               verbose_name=_("Sites"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Site permission")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Site permissions")
```

How can I add a specific user in a view to a specific site? I have not found any documentation regarding this.

Comment: Mezzanine already has this built in - you can assign staff users to particular sites, and they will only be able to edit those sites. You don't need a custom model do do this. When you create the user, there is `Sites` multi-select field where you specify which sites they have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
from mezzanine.core.models import SitePermission
siteperms = SitePermission.objects.create(user=user)
siteperms.sites.add(site)
```